# Remove the equal custom objects between arraylists1 and arraylist2 into arraylist1

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, java-8, time-complexity, space-complexity

I have 2 arraylists with me list1 and list 2. Both of them can have the same custom objects. Say employee class objects, which has 2 attributes i.e. empId and empName.

List1 and List2 can have some equal objects. My objective is to remove the objects which are equal in both arraylist1 and arraylist2 into --> arraylist1.

I have tried the below snippet, however, I am looking for an efficient solution/algorithm in terms of time complexity and space complexity.

```
list1.removeAll(list1.stream().filter((list2)::contains).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Is this alright or do we have a better solution to achieve this using java 8? Thanks for your help.

Comment: "remove into" is hard to understand. I think what you mean is that you want replace `list1` with the intersection of `list1` and `list2`. So that if `list1=[1,2,3,4]` and `list2=[2,4,9]`, then at the end, `list1=[2,4]`. Is that correct?

Comment: Or do you want `list1` to contain the items that *aren't* in `list2`? You really need to clarify your question.

Comment: I want list1 to contain the items that are not in list 2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`removeIf`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html#removeIf-java.util.function.Predicate-) which does a single traversal as:

```
list1.removeIf(list2::contains);
```